# Throw exception, even with correct data type

Tags: java, exception

I've build a currency conversion program, and it takes user input. At a point in the program, I ask for the currency to which they would like to convert. However, nothing is stopping them from putting in "java" as a currency, or any other word.

Here's my current code, I'll explain a little more what I'm looking for further down:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exchange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            while ( i > 0){
                double USDrate = 0.12808;
                double EURrate = 0.107643821;
                double GBPrate = 0.098872935;
                System.out.println("Hello, what currency would you like to convert to?");
                System.out.println("Types: USD  /  EUR  / GBP");
                String type = inn.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Hello, how much would you like to convert?");
                double NOK = inn.nextDouble();
                if( type.equalsIgnoreCase("USD")){
                        System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals $%.2f \n", (NOK*USDrate));
                }else if( type.equalsIgnoreCase("EUR")){
                        System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals €%.2f \n", (NOK*EURrate));
                }else if( type.equalsIgnoreCase("GBP")){
                        System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals £%.2f \n", (NOK*GBPrate));
                }else {
                    // This is where I would like to throw an exception if what they put in doesn't make sense.
                }
                inn.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Would you like to convert more?");
                System.out.println(" YES / NO ");
                String ans = inn.nextLine();
                if( ans.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
                        i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You've entered an incorrect value! Restart.");
        }
    }
}
```

I want the exception to take place under the last `else`-statement within the `while`-loop, as you can see I have a comment there saying exactly that. I would also like to have the same exception in the block of code where I ask whether they would like to convert more.

Anyone able to help? If any details you need are missing, I will give them upon request.

Thanks in advance.

I figured out how to make it the way I wanted it. No exception needed, but here's my solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exchange {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            while ( i > 0){
                double USDrate = 0.12808;
                double EURrate = 0.107643821;
                double GBPrate = 0.098872935;
                System.out.println("Hello, what currency would you like to convert to?");
                System.out.println("Types: USD  /  EUR  / GBP");
                String type = inn.nextLine();
                if(!type.equalsIgnoreCase("USD") && !type.equalsIgnoreCase("EUR") && !type.equalsIgnoreCase("GBP")){
                    System.out.println("Not available currency! Try again.");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("How much would you like to convert?");
                double NOK = inn.nextDouble();
                if( type.equalsIgnoreCase("USD")){
                        System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals $%.2f \n", (NOK*USDrate));
                }else if( type.equalsIgnoreCase("EUR")){
                        System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals €%.2f \n", (NOK*EURrate));
                }else if( type.equalsIgnoreCase("GBP")){
                        System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals £%.2f \n", (NOK*GBPrate));
                }
                inn.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Would you like to convert more?");
                System.out.println(" YES / NO ");
                String ans = inn.nextLine();
                if( ans.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
                        i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("You've entered an incorrect value! Restart.");
        }
    }
}
```

Used another method :) Thanks for the answers anyways, they helped a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? You appear to be 99% of the way there. Also, you dont necessarily need an exception here. You could just pre-check the currency, and loop while the input is bad.

Comment: To "have an exception" you need to throw it: `throw new SomeException()`, but I don't think that's what you want

Comment: How would you go about pre-checking the currency and "loop while the input is bad" ? If you don't mind. I'm very fresh, so I'm don't understand all the terms yet. Why do I not want an exception and when would I want it? Pardon all the questions, but I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exchange {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i = 1;
        Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (i > 0) {
            double USDrate = 0.12808;
            double EURrate = 0.107643821;
            double GBPrate = 0.098872935;
            System.out.println("Hello, what currency would you like to convert to?");
            System.out.println("Types: USD  /  EUR  / GBP");
            String type = inn.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Hello, how much would you like to convert?");
            double NOK = inn.nextDouble();
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("USD")) {
                System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals $%.2f \n", (NOK * USDrate));
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("EUR")) {
                System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals €%.2f \n", (NOK * EURrate));
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("GBP")) {
                System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals £%.2f \n", (NOK * GBPrate));
            } else {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            inn.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Would you like to convert more?");
            System.out.println(" YES / NO ");
            String ans = inn.nextLine();
            if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
        /*(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You've entered an incorrect value! Restart.");*/
}
```

It will throw an Exception in the else part.In your code else part will not work as there is an exception it will go to catch block directly.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions, because this attempt makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an `if/else if... block` i suggest using a switch statement. In the default case you can throw an Exception. Because you're catching `Exception` just make `throw new Exception();`

```
           type = type.toUpperCase();
            switch(type) {
                case "USD":
                    System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals $%.2f \n", (NOK*USDrate));
                break;

                case "EUR":
                    System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals €%.2f \n", (NOK*EURrate));
                break;

                case "GBP":
                    System.out.printf(NOK + "kr equals £%.2f \n", (NOK*GBPrate));
                break;

                default:
                    throw new Exception();
            }
```

And don't forget to close the scanner

```
        finally {
            inn.close();
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what does the 'switch'-statement do? Could you break it down for me? I'm very new to programming.

Do i need to close the Scanner when it doesn't read from file?

Comment: there is absolutely no functional difference between `switch` and `if/elseif/else` And you should never close `System.in`.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson even if there is no functional difference between `switch` and `if else`, a switch is more clear to read in my opinion. Can u explain or give me a link to a source why you should never close `System.in`? I got teached that you should always close a scanner?!

Comment: [Yeah, well, that's just, like, your opinion, man.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c) and that is the problem with the *"answer"*, beside the other harmful advice of closing `System.in`.